# How can I remove an element added by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want list items moved to a div when clicked and vice versa. But it seems, only elements loaded from the source can be moved.

How can I do that? 
Thanks.

```
 <div class="green">
    <ul id="selectable">
        <li class="content-item">Item A</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="red">
    <span class="selected-item">Item 1</span>
    <span class="selected-item">Item 1</span>
    <span class="selected-item">Item 1</span>
    <span class="selected-item">Item 1</span>
    <span class="selected-item">Item 1</span>
    <span class="selected-item">Item 1</span>
    <span class="selected-item">Item 1</span>
</div>

<script>

$(".selected-item").click(function() {
    var text =  "<li class='content-item' >"+$(this).text()+"</li>";
    $(".green #selectable").prepend( text );
    $(this).remove();
});

$(".content-item").click(function() {
    var text =  "<span class='selected-item'>"+$(this).text()+"</span>";
    $(".red").append( text );
    $(this).remove();
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGz8s/112/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [jQuery's event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

The problem is: your jsFiddle is using jQuery 1.4 (very old version), and it doesn't have the `.on` event.

I've updated it to the version 1.11, and it works like a charm:

```
$(".abc").on("click", "span", function(e) {
    var text =  "<li class='content-item' >"+$(e.target).text()+"</li>";
    $(".choices #selectable").prepend( text );
    $(e.target).remove();
});

$(".choices").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    var text =  "<span class='selected-item'>"+$(e.target).text()+"</span>";
    $(".abc").append( text );
    $(e.target).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGz8s/113/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `event delegation` here since the elements that you are adding at the runtime would not be available during event binding,

```
$(document).on("click",".selected-item", function() {
   var text =  "<li class='content-item' >"+$(this).text()+"</li>";
   $(".green #selectable").prepend( text );
   $(this).remove();
});
```

and

```
$(document).on("click",".content-item", function() {
  var text =  "<span class='selected-item'>"+$(this).text()+"</span>";
  $(".red").append( text );
  $(this).remove();
});
```

And in the place of the document in my code use a static closest dom element of the selector which is being passed inside `.on()`